# Issue while exposing method as webservices

Tags: eclipse, web-services, cxf

Here is the code what i used to expose as webservices

```
rs = st.executeQuery(individualqueries);
columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
int numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
int j = 0;
for (j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) 
{
   columnNames.add(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(j));
}

queryResult.fields.addAll(columnNames);
records = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
while (rs.next()) {

   List<String> fieldValues = new ArrayList<String>();
   int k = 0;
   for (k = 1; k <= numCols; k++) {

      fieldValues.add(rs.getString(k));
   }

   records.add(fieldValues);
}
```

When i try to expose this i am getting error message as follows

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of     IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
    at private java.util.List
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the types from `List` to `ArrayList`, which is a concrete implementation of `List`.